# export database to csv usign rest api

Tags: php, rest, csv, slim

Hi I have this code which works if i'm using it as go to page for exporting database..my problem is when i use it for rest api( slim ) i dont how to make it work ..i'm using postman for testing

```
public function export()
{

    $qur =  mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM `tbl_brands`");

    // Enable to download this file
    $filename = "sampledata.csv";

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");

    $display = fopen("php://output", 'w');

    $flag = false;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qur)) {
        if(!$flag) {
          // display field/column names as first row
          fputcsv($display, array_keys($row), ",", '"');
          $flag = true;
        }
        fputcsv($display, array_values($row), ",", '"');
      }

    fclose($display);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slim is based on PSR-7. Here is an example pseudo code to generate and download a CSV file (not tested):

```
public function downloadCsvAction(Request $request, Response $response): ResponseInterface
{
    $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM `tbl_brands`");

    $filename = "sampledata.csv";

    $stream = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');

    $flag = false;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        if (!$flag) {
            // add field/column names as first row
            fputcsv($stream, array_keys($row), ",", '"');
            $flag = true;
        }
        fputcsv($stream, array_values($row), ",", '"');
    }
    rewind($stream);

    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

    return $response->withBody(new \Slim\Http\Stream($stream));
}
```